# Compressing data structure in flatbuffer increases file size?

Tags: flatbuffers

I was trying to optimize my flatbuffer size by creating a compressed schema     for the most repetitive struct I have (using only the 20 LSB bits of ints and slicing them into 64 bits words), the result is not what I was expecting: the file size grew a bit instead of the drastic compression I was expecting, why my 2 ulong + 1 uint struct (2nd case) below takes more space than the explicit struct (1rst case) in the file generated?
In my example, a 2.4Mb file using the explicit struct became a 2.6M using the compressed one....

Explicit Struct, direct access to fields:

```
table VObject {
    m_field1:uint; 
    m_field2:uint;
    m_field3:ushort;
    m_field4:ushort;
    m_field5:uint;
    m_field6:uint;
    m_field7:uint;
    m_field8:uint;
}
```

Compressed Struct, need encoding and decoding using 20 and 16 bit masks:

```
table VObject {
    m_field1:ulong; 
    m_field2:ulong;
    m_field3:uint;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one has 28 bytes worth of fields, and the second one 20. However, mixing `ulong` and `uint` often causes the `uint` to need alignment padding, so it often becomes 24 bytes. The first one doesn't have such a problem because the two `ushort` always go together.

Still, the second should be smaller. Hard to tell what is going on without seeing the kind of data you're storing, how much of it etc.

For example, all fields above have a default value of `0`. If the first one has more fields that are typically `0`, then they won't be stored, and that could explain the smaller size, if for the second fields are always non-zero.

Another compression trick you can try is using a `struct` instead of a `table`. This will not store a vtable, so can be slightly smaller, but always stores all fields, and cannot be changed once defined.

Going even further, using a vector per field as opposed to a vector of structs may help.